# Print all k-mer of strings that are in a file

Tags: c, substring

I have a file that contains a list of strings. I try to generate all k-mer of these. This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char* substr(const char *string, size_t start, size_t end) {

  const char *char_start = &string[start];
  const char *char_end = &string[end];

  char *substring = (char *) calloc(1, char_end - char_start + 1);
  memcpy(substring, char_start, char_end - char_start + 1);

  return substring;
}

int main(void) {
  FILE *file;
  file = fopen("out/clean_read_1.txt", "r");
  if (file == NULL) {
    perror("File not found!\n");
    exit(0);
  } 

  char *line = NULL;
  size_t i, len = 0, k = 5;
  ssize_t read;

  while ( (read = getline(&line, &len, file)) != -1 ) {
    for ( i = 0; i < strlen(line) - k; i++ )
      printf("%s\n", substr(line, i, i + k - 1));
  }

  printf("\n");

  fclose(file);

  return 0;
}
```

This is the file:

```
ACCAG
CAGTGAA
TGAACGGTA
```

I don't understand why the code don't generate the last k-mer.

Expected correct output:

```
ACCAG
CAGTG
AGTGA
GTGAA
TGAAC
GAACG
AACGG
ACGGT
CGGTA
```

Incorrect output of my code:

```
ACCAG
CAGTG
AGTGA
GTGAA
TGAAC
GAACG
AACGG
ACGGT
```

Comment: All information needed to answer the question should appear in the question itself. In addition to example code demonstrating the problem, that should include any required input data (small, please), the expected output, and the actual output.  As text, if in fact the output is textual.  Links to external sites are not acceptable for this purpose.

Comment: `memcpy(substring, char_start, char_end - char_start + 1);` You forgot to NUL-terminate the string.(plus:you (probably) dont need the+1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I noticed that every line in your file except the last one ends with a `'\n'`. Since `getline()` also writes the `\n` into `line` (when it is found in the file), then `strlen(line)` will always be one more than the number of visible characters in that line, EXCEPT when working with the last line since it doesn't contain `'\n'`.

As an example, when working with the second to last line in your file, `line` will contain `"CAGTGAA\n\0"`. Not counting the terminating `'\0'`, those are 7 alphabetic character + the `'\n'`-character. A total of 8 which will be what `strlen(line)` will return. Therefore `strlen(line) - k` will be equal to 3 resulting in the `for`-loop looping 3 times.

But when working with the last line in your file, `line` will contain `"TGAACGGTA\0"`. Not counting the terminating `'\0'`, those are 9 alphabetic character but NO `'\n'`-character so `strlen(line)` will only return 9. Therefore `strlen(line) - k` will be equal to 4 resulting in the `for`-loop only looping 4 times instead of 5 times resulting in the 5th k-mer not being generated.

What you need to do is one of the following:

A)
Add an empty line at the end of your file so that the currently last line also ends with a `'\n'`.

or: 
B)
Change the `for`-loop:

```
  while ( (read = getline(&line, &len, stdin)) != -1 ) {
    for ( i = 0; line[i+k-1] != '\n' && line[i+k-1] != '\0'; i++ )
```

or:
C)
Overwrite `'\n'` when it's at the end of the line with a terminating `'\0'` so that the lines only contain the alphabetic characters you want to work with. Then change the condition in the `for`-loop to take into account that the lines are now one character shorter than before. (Note that since `getline()` returns the number of characters writen,not counting `'\0'`, and you store that in `read`, then there is no need to recalculate the lenght of the string again and again):

```
  while ( (read = getline(&line, &len, stdin)) != -1 ) {
    if (line[read - 1] == '\n') line[--read] = '\0';
    for ( i = 0; i <= read - k; i++ )
```

---

There is at least one more problems with your code. You allocate space for `substring` each time `substr()` is called but you never free it, resulting in a memory leak (strictly speaking you should also free `line`).